# Getting errors while trying to box a colored text + math with less than 6 lines of code

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox, box

First time Latex user here

I am trying to box a text plus math using the following code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\fbox{
{\color{blue} This is a text \[x\]}
}

\boxed{
{\color{blue} This is a text \[x\]}
}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, in doing so, I received 10 errors. [image]

Can anyone help me debug these mere 6 lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! The easiest way to do this is by using the [`framed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{framed}
\color{blue}This is a text \[x\]
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image: framed]

---

You mentioned `tcolorbox` in one of your tags, so here is an alternative using the [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\color{blue}This is a text \[x\]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: tcolorbox]

Answer (score 2):

`\fbox` is an `\hbox` (LR-mode in the LaTeX book) which does not allow line breaks, and `\[` is (after error checking) `$$`so you end up (if you scroll past errors) with

```
\hbox{ text $$x$$}
```

In in restricted hmode `$$` at the primitive level so this is just the same as two `$` so it is

```
     \hbox{ text $ empty math $ x $ empty math $}
```

so as always to get multi-line text into a single-line context you can use a parbox

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\textcolor{blue}{This is a text \[x\]}%
}}



\end{document}
```